# Typeahead not sugesset anything

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-typeahead

i have a html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "brown", "black"];
    $('#vahid').typeahead({source: colors});
</script>
<input type="text" id="vahid" data-provide='typeahead'>
```

but typeahead does not suggest anything. my page has no error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You execute typeahead on not existing element try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "brown", "black"];
        $('#vahid').typeahead({source: colors});
    })
</script>
<input type="text" id="vahid" data-provide='typeahead'>
```

Now code will execute after all dom elements are downloaded